# send intent with extrastring from activity to tab fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

My app's activity hierarchy is:
MainActivity > FragActivity > FragmentExp(It includes 3 tab fragment(`Tab1` `Tab2` `Tab3`))

I have recycler view in `MainActivity` and when clicked in different list I want to go to `Tabs` with extrastrings(I mean some string message). And, show toast in those tabs.

What I've tried is:
I set intent with extrastring from my `MainActivity` to `FragActivity` like this.

```
 if (position==1){
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FragActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(MainActivity.ENGLISHPDF, "0");
            startActivity(i);
        }
```

and get those strings directly in `Tab1` and `Tab2` like this:
**In `Tab1`**

```
code = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.ENGLISHPDF);
        if (this.code.equals("0")) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "hey its 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

**In `Tab2`**

```
code = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.ENGLISHPDF);
        if (this.code.equals("0")) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "hey its 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

These are my codes:

**MainActivity**:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, DataAdapter.OnNoteListener{
    public static final String ENGLISHPDF = "english";
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        (...)

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.add_header);
        (...)

        ArrayList<ListItem> items =  new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new Item(R.drawable.green, "English", "1"));
        DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter(items, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNoteClick(int position) {

        if (position==0){
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FragActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(MainActivity.ENGLISHPDF, "0");
            startActivity(i);
        }
       }
    }
```

**FragActivity**:

```java
public class FragActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_frag);


        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,
                new FragmentExplorem(), COLLAPSING_TOOLBAR_FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();


    }
```

And finally in FragExp I've set tablayout and include 3 tabs fragment in it.
This is FragExp:

```java
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, container, false);

        AppBarLayout appBarLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_appbar_layout);
        ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams()).setBehavior(new AppBarLayoutBehavior());

        tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_CENTER);

        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(tab_count);

        toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setupToolbar();

        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0: return new Tab1();
                case 1: return new Tab2();
                case 2: return new Tab3();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tab_count;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                 case 0 : {
                    return "First";

                }
                case 1 : {
                    return "Second";

                }
                case 2 : {
                    return "Third";
                }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's your problem? I dont get it

Comment: @HaiHack I want to send intent to specific tab fragment

Comment: is FragmentExp a Fragment or Activity?

Comment: @HaiHack it is a fragment

Comment: @HaiHack I just added its code in question

Comment: you should put the code string into a Bundle then use Fragment.setArguments(Bundle bundle) instead of using intent

Comment: @yyp can you please explain it more. I'm new in fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get fragment instance like following function.
This way of getting instance ensures all the clients need the 
 instance have the same process of constructing the Fragment.

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    private static final String KEY_CODE = "key_code";

    public static Fragment newInstance(@Nullable String code) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle(1);
        if (code!= null)
            args.putString(KEY_CODE, code);

        Tab1 fragment = new Tab1();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

when you need Tab1 instance, you should pass the parameter or null at the same time.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0: return Tab1.newInstance(code);
        case 1: return Tab2.newInstance(code);
        case 2: return Tab3.newInstance(code);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then you can use the code by invoking Fragment.getArguments().

```
// In Tab1
private String mCode;

private String DEFAULT_CODE = "0";

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mCode = getArguments().getString(KEY_CODE , DEFAULT_CODE);
    // Now you can use the mCode in any place in Tab1 you want, but make sure you do Null check before using it
}
```

BTW, if the "code" is dynamic, then it will be totally different.

Comment: and what should i do in onNoteClick of MainActivity?

Comment: it is fine to use intent to pass parameter between MainActivity and FragActivity, because they are both Activity right?

Comment: I'm not getting where should I keep these codes? I want to show toast message in different tab when clicking position 0 through intent extrastrings.

Comment: each code will be store in mCode of relevant fragment once they are created

Comment: it is showing error in tab1.newInstance(code)
in `newInstance`

Comment: turn type? I changed public static Tab1 to Fragment but it is still showing error

Comment: my bad, change the return type of function newInstance from Tab1 to Fragment

Comment: is this `mCode = getArguments().getString(KEY_CODE , DEFAULT_CODE);
        if (this.mCode.equals("0")) {  //where "0" is extrastring from MainActivity
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "hey its 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }` ?

Comment: okay, It is working.
Last question:
why is it necessary to do Null check before using it?
and bundle(1) or bundle() same??

Comment: Sorry, my fault again. There's no need to do Null check because we have given mCode a defaultCode if there's no string in arguments.
Answer for second question, bundle(1) initials with one capacity, where bundle initials with zero. For more detail please check official documents for [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle#Bundle(int))